# Remodeling an old IE6 only web page using QTWebKit

Tags: html, qt, internet-explorer, qtwebkit

Problem -> The company I work for, has a really bad_old_nasty IE6 only "sales webpage", and it cames to a point that people are using winXP inside virtualbox to work on that. Compatibility mode from modern IE makes their system really slow.

Question -> It is possible, using all the QTWebKit's magic, to intercept and create a new "look and feel" for this old system? For example, change the font type, font size, colors, tables position, drop menus? {if possible, please provide a PoC}

Why -> Because they cannot touch the contents that resides on the server side. 1 - the company that made the system no longer exists. 2 - there's no support. 3 - the executives believe in the "if it works, don't touch it". 3 - the website is totally broke and non functional in other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, you name it)

Thank you all for your time and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Cannot provide a PoC without first seeing the PoS.  But sounds like attempts to revive it would be a waste of more time and more money.  How hard could it be to create a "Sales Page" ?

Comment: If people are required to use an out-of-date OS in a virtualbox to access the sales page, I would state this is at least 2 generations past the **it works so do not touch it** state. I hope you're in a position to convince the executive that time has come for something new.

Comment: @2-centstim -> Hi, thanks for you answer. Actually it's not PoS. Think about old cobol bank systems or those bank webpages that only works in IE. It is a sales prospect hand made for old databases, and deployment to a series of authorized prospectors.

That's why I was thinking about qtnetwork to manipulating headers, post, get, and so. And qtwebkit to embed a custom website view inside the qt app.

Comment: @Bowdzone ->  Hi, thanks for you answer. Please see the above comment to "2-centstim".